# Ethereum DApp with user authentication

Tags: contract-development, truffle, blockchain, solidity-0.5.x, ganache-cli

I'm creating a healthcare DApp and how can I create user authentication ( For Doctor and Patient). I'm using JavaScript and HTML for most of my UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let them sign in via Metamask.
You can let them sign without using any gas.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial